# Can one extend WPF's ICommand behavior for controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, icommand

When an item has its Command property bound to an ICommand, you can expect its enabled state to rely on ICommand.CanExecute. What I would like to do is make an interface, inheriting from ICommand, that provides a "MayExecute" to do the same for control visibility. Is there a clean way to do this without effectively recompiling .NET?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into doing this with an attached property. I think it's doable (and pretty cool too).

The attached property would have a method to check if the value of `Command` on the target control implements `IVanishingCommand` or whatever you call it. If so, it subscribes to `MayExecuteChanged` and overrides the control's visibility as appropriate.

You'd call that method again when `Command` gets a new value (and be sure to unsubscribe from the old `Command`'s event).

Use reflection to get the control's `Command` dependency property; `Button` and `MenuItem`, for example, don't both inherit `Command` from any common base class.

You might be able to do this with a trigger in a Style too -- but it would soon get horrible to do it in all those different styles.